# How can I use a .ovpn file with Network Manager?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I have a .ovpn file with my VPN config - it works fine when I do

```
sudo openvpn --config ~jrg/Documents/vpn-config.ovpn
```

in the terminal, but I'd like to use Network Manager. How can I do this?

Comment: In terminal `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file /path/to/your.ovpn` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-import-openvpn-ovpn-file-with-networkmanager-commandline/

Comment: @chepe263 Make this an answer, you get my vote (BTW, NM architecture is such that `sudo` is *NOT* required with the connection import)

Comment: @chepe263 doesn't work for me: `Error: failed to import 'file.ovpn': configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element (line 7).`

Answer (score 206, accepted):

First, install the OpenVPN Network Manager plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Open Network Manager, click "Add" and from the opened window select "Import a saved VPN configuration..." under "Choose a Connection Type". Navigate to your .ovpn file (~jrg/Documents/vpn-config.ovpn). If it doesn't automatically find your certificates/keys (the paths of which are found in the .ovpn file), you can select them here, or make any other small changes.

[image: openvpn dialog]

One other thing that may save you some headache down the road is to click IPv4 Settings, then change the method to "Automatic (VPN) Addresses Only". When kept at the default, this will cause ALL internet traffic to go over the VPN, regardless of your .ovpn settings. Here you can also set the DNS server and search domains to use while connected.

[image: openvpn dialog]

Comment: It doesn't show the certificates and such when I click "Import".

Comment: I updated my answer to be a little more thorough. If the options just aren't showing up, than you either have a misconfigured .ovpn and aren't actually using them, or you need to change the "Type" drop-down box.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: there is a bug in network manager for ovpn files. see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365

Comment: there's no "Import..." button in my case (using debian jessie...) :(

Comment: I too cannot find any "import" buttons. Only a "create" option.. :(

Comment: Open VPN AS ver 2.0.12 does not produce a .ovpn files that contains the locations of certs, it contains them itself. Therefore if will not find them and you can not find the location. You have to copy n paste like in the other answer.

Comment: I had to copy and paste as well: " VPN AS ver 2.0.12 does not produce a .ovpn files that contains the locations of certs, it contains them itself. Therefore if will not find them and you can not find the location. You have to copy n paste"

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the window with the "Import" button?

Comment: @naktinis Sorry it is in french, but here it is : https://github.com/dolanor/ovpnsplit/raw/master/doc/02-import-vpn-config.png

Comment: as of 16.04, It's still not working and at least this time you get "import is not supported in the plugin". Network manager still has issues even when manually configured

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/openvpn-config-splitter to split .ovpn into separate files

Comment: The  network-manager-openvpn-gnome plugin will only recognize 2.3 "remote vpn.site.com \n
port 1194 \n
proto tcp" not the new oneliner in 2.4 "remote vpn.site.com port 1194 tcp-client" it also requires a "something" in the form for the private key password even if the key is not protected

Comment: https://git.gnome.org/browse/network-manager-openvpn/tag/?h=1.8.2 may provide better support

Comment: I'm getting an error in Xubuntu, it says that the plugin doesn't support the import capability, however, the import button appeared after installing the plugin.

Answer (score 53):

Since ubuntu 18.04, if you already have the opvn file you can import it. (sudo is not required)

```
nmcli connection import type openvpn file [client].ovpn
```

Once done, go to search and find 'network', the new vpn connection will be there.

Comment: Thanks, this is way better than fooling around in the Network Manager GUI. (I don't even have to use sudo if nm-applet is owned by me)

Comment: works also on Debian 10, IMHO since the OP inquired how to import, this should be the answer

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 18, just one fact if it continuously asks for password even if you are entering correct password, please check the configuration, I had to manually enter the username, password by editing the config via GUI.

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment to the OP, `sudo` is *NOT* required given NM's architecture.

Answer (score 36):

My own experience of successful VPN connection establishing on Ubuntu 14.04.

Our admin gave me 3 files to install them into openVPN for Windows 7: *.ovpn, *.crt, *.key

1. Execute the following commands in your Ubuntu terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc
   sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```
2. Open "Network Connections" window (VPN Connections -> Configure VPN)
3. Press "ADD" button, click on drop-down menu and pick "Import a saved VPN configuration", press Create button.
4. In "Select File to import" choose your "*.ovpn" file.
5. In "Editing ...your *.ovpn file name..." window enter your username and password for vpn. Make sure that a *.crt file appeared in CA Certificate field.
6. Open "IPv4 Settings" panel and choose "Automatic (VPN) addresses only".
7. Open "VPN" panel again and click "Advanced" button.
8. Open "TLS Authentication" panel and make sure your "*.key" appeared in "Key File" field. Press Ok button.
9. Press "Save" button in "Editing ...your *.ovpn file name..." window.
10. Your VPN connection should appear in "Network Connections" window.

That's all, I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: this worked for me but without step 8.

Answer (score 13):

It's late to answer, but I found a solution (and it is a PAIN)...

1. Create a folder in your home directory called **.OpenVPN** (with the dot in front of it so it is hidden) then open that folder and create one called **FrootVPN** (no dot needed).  This makes management of different VPN providers easier.
2. Copy/Paste froot.ovpn to the /home/YOU/.OpenVPN/FrootVPN folder.
3. Open the froot.ovpn file with a text editor.
4. Copy everything between the ca /ca tags.
5. Paste the contents to a new file and save it as **ca.crt** within the /home/YOU/.OpenVPN/FrootVPN folder.
6. Click on the Network Manager icon and go to VPN CONNECTIONS > CONFIGURE VPN...
7. Click on ADD and select OpenVPN.  Click CREATE.
8. Call it **FrootVPN 1194** and use **se-openvpn.frootvpn.com** for the Gateway.  Type will be PASSWORD.  Enter your FrootVPN username and password.  On CA Certificate, click the folder icon and browse to the ca.crt file you created.
9. Click the Advanced button and change "Use custom gateway port:" to 1194.  Click OK.
10. Change the Method on both the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs to **Automatic (VPN) addresses only**.
11. Click SAVE.

Now for the PAIN part: you will have to create 15 more FrootVPN connections since they use ports 1194-1209.  Repeat Steps 7-11 above for port 1195 then again for 1196 and so on until you finish with port 1209 making sure the name in Step 8 matches the port in Step 9.  I know... it sucks!

Now you can connect to FrootVPN by clicking on the Network Manager icon and going to VPN Connections.  Work through the list of FrootVPN connections until you find one you can connect to.

Frankly, I wish Network Manager supported .ovpn files directly.  We should be able to IMPORT the .ovpn file, Network Manager gets all the correct settings from the .ovpn file, does the correct range of gateway ports and other settings specified by the VPN provider, and saves it all as ONE connection.  The .crt files should not be needed if everything is in the .ovpn file.

Comment: this totally sucks, anyone know if there is an offical bug report anywhere ?

Comment: I know.  It DOES totally suck.  I wish there was a simple GUI that opens them like Windows has.

Comment: *It's late to answer...* its 2019 now and this answer still saved my day, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In Unity 14.04, all I had to do was go to edit connections, Click "add" by using the drop down list to select import a saved VPN configuration, and then select my "filename.ovpn" file, and voila. Done.

Comment: This looks promising, but it barely uses my .ovpn at all, it just pulls out the gateway. None of the certificates are present. :\

Comment: This worked for me, no problems. Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

I answered this with a way to use Network Manager as the OP asked, but there is a MUCH BETTER WAY!  All you have to do is download and install a program called gopenvpn which is available via Ubuntu Software Center.  Save your .ovpn files to /etc/openvpn as admin.  Open gopenvpn which should be listed under Applications > Internet and click on the .ovpn file to connect to by right-clicking on the gopenvpn icon you will see on your task bar.  Easy as pie which is the way anything on a computer should be :)

Also you can bypass usernames and password by making .txt files in /etc/openvpn using this format:

```
username
password
```

Then in each of your .ovpn files (for example VPNBook .ovpn files), change the line that says this:

```
auth-user-pass
```

To:

```
auth-user-pass VPNBook.txt
```

Use `SED` to make the replacement per line in all your .ovpn -files, etc

```
root@masi:/etc/openvpn# sed -i '/auth-user-pass/c\auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt' *.ovpn
```

Lastly ensure security and do such that others do not see your username and password

```
root@masi:/etc/openvpn# chmod 700 nordvpn.txt
```

Comment: Use `sed` to replace the thing in all your .ovpn -files etc `root@masi:/etc/openvpn# sed -i '/auth-user-pass/c\auth-user-pass nordvpn.txt' *.ovpn` where the password file locates in `/etc/openvpn/`. - - Related: https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/

Comment: Please, pay more attention to security. Your password would be open to others.

Comment: Also protect the file before putting sensitive info inside. `600` should be the file permissions and owner should be `root` I assume. I don't see how is this better than importing with `nmcli` or network manager UI whatever you are using (depends on DE).

Answer (score 5):

Since this issue bit me quite a few times, I decided to also create a tool to automate the "downgrading" of the .ovpn file with embedded certs to a .ovpn file pointing to other .pem files.

It is available here : https://github.com/dolanor/ovpnsplit/
It is in go, so you need go installed or you can just use the binaries from here : https://github.com/dolanor/ovpnsplit/releases

Put your .ovpn file where you want it (I put it in ~/.config/openvpn/ that I created), then launch the tool

`ovpnsplit ~/.config/openvpn/file.ovpn`

It will create all the files that were embedded in `file.ovpn` into individual `.pem` files

In NetworkManager, select import vpn config and then choose your `~/.config/openvpn/file.ovpn`. Normally, all the certificate files should point to the good one.

But another bug made that NetworkManager doesn't detect the key direction from the Advanced settings of TLS Auth. So you need to put it to the right direction also…

And after that, you save and you should be good to go.

This tool will help with the use of the [kylemanna/openvpn](http://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn) docker image which create all the certificates and the TLS Auth.

Comment: do you know which version of ubuntu will be the first one to allow .opvn files with embedded certs? (in order to resort to ovpnsplit, which is a great tool, don't get me wrong)

Comment: Given this : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365 . It seems it has been fixed. I think we're still before feature freeze, and since it is a bug it might get to the 16.04 anyway. I guess you were the knocte posting on this bug :)

Comment: yes I were the one posting there, but nobody replied :(

Answer (score 2):

I created a script [here](https://github.com/ryanniehaus/useful_scripts/blob/master/openvpn_conversion_for_network-manager/update_vpnprovidersinfo_and_extract_certs.sh) to automate fetching password & zip files from several vpn sites such as [vpnbook.com](http://vpnbook.com), extracting the `ca`, `cert`, and `key` data from the ovpn files, and updating the opvn files so the certs should just import for you.  It could easily be modified for use with other providers.

Answer (score 0):

When you aren't given an user certificate, you must select the 'Password' type in the authentication drop down. Then in advanced, in 'TLS Authentication' add the TLS .key file and set the direction accordingly (1 or 0, that should be set in the .ovpn file).