# Asus RT-A66U OpenVPN client on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have an Asus RT-AC66U router with an openvpn server which I've connected to successfully numerous times on Windows using the openvpn client. I want to set up a client on Ubuntu 16.04. To do this I've followed instructions from other questions like: [How can I use a .ovpn file with Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187511/how-can-i-use-a-ovpn-file-with-network-manager) (They all seem to say pretty much the same thing.)
But when I try to connect I get a pop up message of:

> The IP config of the VPN connection was invalid.

And when I look at my router's system log there is a single error saying

> openvpn[15587]: client/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for client/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx

I get the feeling like this is an either an iptables or a dns problem but I can't find any help suitable for this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!