# Ubuntu 18.04 no DNS resolution when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: dns, openvpn, systemd-resolved

When I connect to a VPN network through Gnome Network-manager I lose DNS resolution and in practice, I cannot access resources inside the VPN network or outside.

When I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and I was using the VPN, the "`/etc/resolv.conf/`" file would contain the DNS servers of the (VPN) network I had connected. Now it always contains the following entries:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search myprovider.com
```

From what I have understood `127.0.0.53` is the address of the DNS stub used by the `system-resolved`.

I suspect that this is a bug because the VPN was working fine the Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any way that I can set the DNS servers of my network when I am using a VPN service?

**Update:**

I tried connecting to the OpenVPN network with the  configuration file attached at the end of the post, but I get the following error:

```
 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: cipher final failed
```

I have verified that the server uses lzo compression and I have enabled it as well. The connection stays active but I cannot navigate to any page inside or outside the VPN.

In the configuration file listed below, I have included the solutions posted in the replies

```
 client
 dev tun
 proto udp
 remote openvpn.bibsys.no 1194
 remote my-server-2 1194
 resolv-retry infinite
 nobind
 user myuser
 group myuser
 persist-key
 persist-tun
 ca ca-cert.pem
 cert openvpn.crt
 key openvpn.key
 cipher AES-256-CBC
 comp-lzo yes
 script-security 2
 up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
 down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
 down-pre
```

Comment: When debugging a similar problem to this that couldn't be solved exactly the same, I used `resolvectl status` and `resolvectl help` to figure out my specific solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found a solution on [this blog post](https://blog.syddel.uk/?p=253). While there are two solutions mentioned, I prefer using the second one because it means my DNS is set by the OpenVPN server (the first solution means I use the same DNS servers whether or not I'm connected to the OpenVPN server).

In short:

- `sudo mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/scripts`
- `sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/master/update-systemd-resolved -P /etc/openvpn/scripts/`
- `sudo chmod +x /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved`

Then edit your OpenVPN client file (e.g. client.ovpn) by changing the up/down scripts to:

```
script-security 2
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
```

(I have commented out the original up/down settings).

Comment: If one is using the gnome openvpn utility where should the file config.ovpn be stored?

Comment: `config.ovpn` isn't "found" - it's the client config file used for connecting. You either generate it, or it is issued to you by your OpenVPN provider (and it might not be called `config.ovpn` - it could be called anything, like `client.ovpn`).

Comment: This works just perfectly.

Comment: I get `WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program fork failed`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn’t work for a vpn which is using tcp, sites outside vpn are not resolved, hence I started using https://client.pritunl.com/#install found useful

Comment: Without `down-pre` in the end of *.ovpn* file, you would get nasty warnings at stop `update-systemd-resolved: Invalid device name: 'tun0'. Usage: update-systemd-resolved up|down device_name.
WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program exited with error status: 1
Exiting due to fatal error`

Comment: This did not work for me either. Am having the exact same issue.

Comment: My client.ovpn file doesn't have up and down lines, can I just add them?

Comment: @Falc Yes, you can.

Comment: Adding the `script-security 2` and (up/down) `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` lines fixed it for me.

Comment: as of 2021-10, there's also the package "openvpn-systemd-resolved" as part of standard repositories, instead of referring to some githubusercontent URL.

Answer (score 132):

**Problem**

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` does not get updated by the `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` script because `resolvconf` is not installed by default on ubuntu 18.04.

In fact, one of the first lines of that script checks for the `/sbin/resolvconf` executable:

```
[ -x /sbin/resolvconf ] || exit 0
```

Installing resolvconf via `apt-get` is not a solution as the `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` script updates the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with the pushed DNS entry but the tun device seems to ignore it.

**Solution**

1. Ubuntu 18.04 uses `systemd-resolved`, so all you have to do is install the openvpn helper script for `systemd-resolved` via

   ```
   sudo apt install openvpn-systemd-resolved
   ```

   or with [these GitHub instructions](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved)
2. Update your `config.ovpn` file adding these lines:

   ```
   script-security 2
   up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
   down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
   down-pre
   ```

   That instead of adding up and down of `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` to the conf.
3. To prevent DNS Leakage, you should add this line to the end of the `config.ovpn` file (according to [this systemd issue comment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6076#issuecomment-387332572)):

   ```
   dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, working for me on Ubuntu 18.04. And I want to specify, that parameter `script-security 2` is still needed before up/down lines, otherwise the program falls down with an error (OpenVPN 2.4.4)

Comment: Glad it helped :)
Changed the last sentence in the answer, with **in my case**  `script-security 2` was not necessary. That's perhaps because I'm running the openvpn client as root (with sudo)

Comment: I am running the client as root and I still (also) need to add `script-security 2` for this setup to work. BTW, thanks a lot for this tip, @Qlimax. :-)

Comment: @Qlimax Do you know how do we import these settings to the gnome openvpn client?

Comment: @orestis you have to install this package `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`  Then you should be able to import .ovpn config files into the gnome network manager. https://askubuntu.com/questions/187511/how-can-i-use-a-ovpn-file-with-network-manager UI has changed over time,  you should be able to find that in settings->network->vpn

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! The last line for preventing dns leakage is necessary because the systems still uses the default dns.

Comment: Surprised this works for so many of you: I have an ovpn.config, yes, but NetworkManager does not seem to use it. Did you edit the file and the re-import it, in particular to replace the up/downs scripts. Because I see this opaque binary /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper used for which i could not find documentation. If re-import of ovpn.config is needed, please amend the answer.

Comment: this worked for me as well

Comment: Can't +1 this enough.  It really should be the accepted answer

Comment: Didn't work for me at first because my resolv.conf was still looking at my router dns. I made sure the stub was used first (127.0.0.53) on ubuntu 19.10, and it worked. I still can't figure out how to get the stub resolver to do the local then remote resolving by itself, but this is a good workaround for now.

Comment: Sorry but not worked with me.

Comment: Is it expected that this should solve Pritunl problems on Ubuntu 20.04 too?

Comment: Thank you! This is still valid for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: the final line `dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .` was critical - my problem wasn't fixed until I added that aswell

Comment: Best. Answer. On the Internet.
Thanks - it took me a while until I found your answer, the part that `resolveconf` should have been installed.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there is a much easier solution to this problem. The issue is with DNS traffic and how Ubuntu 18 manages that. By default IP forwarding is disabled which is what OpenVPN needs in order to provide proper networking. All you have to do is run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Once you have this file opened, look for the line that contains `net.ipv4.ip_forward`. If this line is commented, remove the # sign at the front of the line (if it is not commented then you have another issue). Save the file and then restart your OpenVPN server instance.

This fix does not require any modifications to the client or OpenVPN code following upgrade to Ubuntu 18. Tested and confirmed working.

However, this obviously requires you can administer the server. And unfortunately, the bug exists for many who just connect with 18.04 to an OpenVPN server that is administered by somebody else...

Comment: didn't work for me.  how did you determine that this was the problem, in  your case?

Comment: WARNING: you do not need to enable ip_forward on the openvpn *client*, NEVER! it is a security risk. On the openvpn *server*, you may need it, depending on the config used and this is probably why this comment show up.

Comment: This was it for me. Weird issue. Thanks.

Comment: this seems to work for me ! Thanks. I tested so many different fixes...

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 at 13 Sep 2018

There is another useful command to setup what you need via command line. You can control your VPN connection both with command line and GUI.

```
sudo nmcli connection add type vpn vpn-type openvpn con-name la.vpn.contoso.com ifname --
```

`ifname --` is the required by default, but does not affect anything

```
sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.dns 172.16.27.1
sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.dns-search int.contoso.com
sudo nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com ipv4.never-default yes
```

`never-default` should not use remote gateway as default route

And much more interested final touch:

```
nmcli connection modify la.vpn.contoso.com vpn.data 'ca = /tmp/la.vpn.contoso.com/you/ca.crt, key = /tmp/you.key, dev = tun, cert = /tmp/you.crt, cert-pass-flags = 1, comp-lzo = adaptive, remote = la.vpn.contoso.com:1194, connection-type = tls'
```

Afterwards you can control vpn with GUI or use following commands:

```
sudo nmcli --ask connection up la.vpn.contoso.com
sudo nmcli connection down la.vpn.contoso.com
```

Answer (score 3):

If your system is using NetworkManager, then you may only need to change the connection's DNS priority, as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229447/518847):

```sh
nmcli -p connection modify VPN_CONNECTION_NAME ipv4.dns-priority -1
```

In my case, the DNS was being updated, but ignored as the existing DNS servers had precedence. You may need root/`sudo`. If that doesn't work, try `ipv6.dns-priority`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm impacted too. In my case, I'm using OpenVPN with an internal name server (which is inside the VPN). That worked until Ubuntu 17.10 (with `hosts: files dns` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).

`/etc/resolv.conf` was updated correctly by the openvpn scripts (through calls to `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` in the openvpn client configuration file).

However, name resolution for hosts inside the VPN was not working any more (or at least sporadically... I guess the local DNS cache was picking the names, but after a rather long time).

What seems to help, or even resolve the issue (though that's too early to say) is to install the below package:

```
sudo apt install openvpn-systemd-resolved
```

Comment: Eventually, it doesn't seem to be a solution. I have the problem again. I guess something else made it work...

Comment: Maybe then you delete your answer? It seems that the decision has already been found below

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed CLI-oriented (non-NetworkManager) solutions worked for me (I don't even have `up` and `down` lines in `myconfig.ovpn`).

However, I've found that NetworkManager VPN seems to work again (it did not work a year or two ago, which is why I switched to openvpn CLI then). I did not tweak it in any way: just tried to activate it with the appropriate credentials.