# Openconnect add dns to systemd-resolve

Tags: networking, openconnect

When connecting to a vpn using openconnect the default vpnc script adds dns servers into my resolv.conf file.

These DNS servers come before my stub resolver 127.0.0.53 which uses systemd-resolve.

After this I can resolve host names in the VPN but not my local ones anymore.

It seems like this problem is related to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn). I wanted to implement the accepted [solution](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) . However, openconnect does not seem to have the required --up and -- down options.

In  the end I don't want openconnect to modify resolv.conf but add DNS entries to systemd-resolve so I can use the stub to resolve both VPN host names and local hostnames.

Can this somehow be achieved with a smart vpnc script?