# How connect to open vpn server without gui?

Tags: openvpn

I cant use mmci and gnome gui on my laptop, because have error:

```
sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file OpenVPN.ovpn 
Ошибка: не удалось импортировать 'OpenVPN.ovpn':
 configuration error: unsupported 3th argument vpn_gateway to “route” (line 13).
```

But i succesfuly connected with:

```
sudo openvpn --config OpenVPN.ovpn
```

and have opened tunnel:

```
tun2: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.10.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.0.10.5
        inet6 fe80::1d06:5638:3178:e66d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100
```

And now, how i can use this tunnel for surfing the Internet through a browser?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, once the VPN tunnel is opened all traffic is automatically routed through that.

Comment: Funny enough, there's a difference between using openvpn via NM and CLI. It appears that you do have an error on line 13 in your .ovpn file... hence it wouldn't import. Edit your question and show us your .ovpn file, xxx out any password/private info.

Answer (score 1):

I cant imported file via gui, because ovpn config have string:
`route x.x.x.x 255.255.0.0 vpn_gateway`
Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365/comments/68

My vpn cant work with console because i have problem in dns, solution(based on [Ubuntu 18.04 no DNS resolution when connected to openvpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn)):

1. Install openvpn
   `sudo apt-get install openvpn`
2. Install openvpn-systemd-resolved
   `sudo apt install openvpn-systemd-resolved libnss-resolve`
3. Edit /etc/nsswitch.conf. Find string "hosts:" and replace to:
   `hosts: files resolve`
4. For application which used /etc/resolv.conf directly create symlink:

```
ln -svi /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

5. Start systemd-resolved:

```
systemctl enable systemd-resolved
systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

6. Edit *.ovpn file, add:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

and at the end of file:

```
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
```

7. Connect to vpn and enjoy

```
sudo openvpn --config my-vpn.ovpn
```