# problem using pritunl VPN client on ubuntu 20.04 due to faulty DNS resolution

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.04, dns, vpn

I am having problems using a VPN with the pritunl client on Ubuntu 20.04.

When using the VPN, I am able to get pings (i.e. `ping 8.8.8.8` is fine), but websites are not loading. From searching online, this should be due to a DNS resolution problem.

I could not find threads specific about Ubuntu 20.04 regarding this problem, while I think this may be dependent on the Ubuntu version (for example, there seemed to be no problems before Ubuntu 16.04).

So far, my search for a solution has lead to:

- I have been told that this is due to a network-manager issue, and been recommended to downgrade to a specific version to solve this, but it does not work as it looks like the last network-manager version without the issue is not available on Ubuntu 20.04:

Commands:

```
$ sudo apt install network-manager=1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1' for 'network-manager' was not found
```

- Another solution found online seems to be valid for Ubuntu 18.04:

[Ubuntu 18.04 no DNS resolution when connected to openvpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn)

I think the second answer (answer by Qlimax, not the accepted one) looks best. Is that expected to work on Ubuntu 20.04 too? Any downside with this? I would like to have confirmation before doing anything, as I do not want to break / compromise anything on my system.

- Finally, I wonder if the post there may also be an answer to this problem:

https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/gnome-client

Then I suppose this bypasses the pritunl client altogether and uses the gnome client, right? Any downsides I should be aware of?

Finally, wondering the following: if this is well a network-manager issue, do you know if a fix is in the pipes? I can find some bug reports online but it does not seem that much is happening, which is surprising...

Comment: Note: a simple workaround may be to use OpenVPN instead. All what was needed was to 1) import the Pritunl profiles: ```for conf in $HOME/.config/pritunl/profiles/*.ovpn; do
nmcli con import file $conf type openvpn
done
``` 2) use the VPN icon in the Ubuntu top right bar.