# Ubuntu 20.04 DNS not work after connect to VPN

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

I have **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**. I added VPN config using this [instruction](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-in-linux/).
VPN is correctly added. When I connect to this VPN I can open only page with address IP.
For example I can `ping` address `8.8.8.8` but I can't ping address `facebook.com`. I get error:

> Temporary failure in name resolution

I trying resolve this by this [instruction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504975/241215). But when I disconnected VPN and next connected to VPN, then inside file `/etc/resolv.conf` disappear `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and I must add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` again.

Comment: If this is through Windscribe, then I have the same issue. They know about the problem but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt they need to define nameservers in the VPN configuration to use - Google DNS nameservers to use.  That'll make it work.  (I've dealt with VPN providers who have to push DNS server configs to endpoints and that's the way they need to do it)

Comment: @ThomasWard They told me that the first time it broke, the site I was trying to visit was on their blacklist like wtf

Comment: @Qlimax solution found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn) worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it added permanently `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Instruction: [Set permanent DNS nameservers on Ubuntu/Debian with resolv.conf](https://www.ricmedia.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-ubuntu-debian-resolv-conf/)

Comment: Did you change the nameserver from 127.0.0.xx or did you add this as a new line?

Comment: I add a new line

Comment: Just I edit resolv.conf using this command `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and added `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. Next I used this command: `sudo resolvconf --enable-updates && sudo resolvconf -u. And when I open file resolv.conf (command: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`) I saw added `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: and if /etc/resolv.conf defalt back automatically, set its attribute to immitable (though I am not so sure it didnt change again on me once when set so)

sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf