# Openvpn connection problem using network manager

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have problem with connecting to vpn my company gave me those files along with a password

[image: openvpn folder]

I tried to import them this way
1- I go to Network Setting
2- then I press the plus button to add new connection
3- then I choose import from file option
4- then I select the `tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn.ovpn` file
5- and finally I put the password and save

after this is I try to connect I get this message

[image: error message]

and if I check the `syslog` I find this error

[image]

I looked around in google and I found two ways

The first way is to use this command line each time I have to connect

```
sudo openvpn /home/pookyfox/Documents/tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn/tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn.ovpn
```

This way is so much boring each time  open my laptop I have to and execute the command and put the password and leave the terminal open

The second way is to import network connection using this command line

```
sudo nmcli c import type openvpn file tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn.ovpn
```

The problem in this way is that if I connect to the network I get a success message but I only have access to the `VPN` not any other website (like google for example) and to resolve the I have to check this `Use this network only for its resources on its network` in the network setting in the IPv4 tab and my guess is that I have overridden some hidden setting when I save after checking that button.

And here's the OpenVPN configuration

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
dh dh2048.pem
cert tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn.crt
key tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn.key
remote [ip_adress] [port]
cipher DES-CBC
verb 2
mute 20
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
float
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

I had to add the `tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"` because I had an other issue.
So my question is how can I use network manager to connect to the VPN ?(just like the second way but with the box checked)

Comment: There are some guides here: https://askubuntu.com/a/643043/486734 and https://askubuntu.com/a/555180/486734, check if they work.

Answer (score 0):

if it works with `sudo`..

try running

`ll /home/pookyfox/Documents/tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn/`

or

`ls -o /home/pookyfox/Documents/tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn/`

and check if your user/group has read/execute rights to those files.
If you see something like these

```
drwx------   8 root root  ...
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  ...
```

but not like these

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root ...
drwxrwxrwt  17 root root ...
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root ...
-rwxrwxrwx   1 pookyfox pookyfox ...
```

just do a `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/pookyfox/Documents/tw-proxmox-ovh_vpn/` and try to re-run them again.

Just throwing the first idea off the top of my head, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already have all the permission for those files, but it's just openVPN problem. I just need to right configuration to make it work through the GUI not the CLI

Comment: Oh I see, at first it seemed to me as if the app wasn't able to read the file. Well I would focus on that OpenSSL error then and  if this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187511) didn't help you in any way, then good luck:)