# Generate OpenVPN client file for creating session to access the company's private networks

Tags: 20.04, vpn, openvpn

In windows, I have installed OpenVPN and entered:

- URL: **openvpn.company.io**
- email: **user@email.com**
- pass: **mypassword**

And I able to access with success organization private networks.

I am trying to do the same on Ubuntu version 20.04. I am trying to install the OpenVPN client to access private networks. I have followed the commands from  the [link](https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/)) and I installed it successfully. I verified by executing the command: `openvpn3 configs-list` and I get the correct result.

I want to create a secure session to access the company's private networks and I am not figuring out how to generate the file `${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}` that is needed to create a session with the command `openvpn3 session-start --config ${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}`.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on what information should I put in `${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}`. I wasn't able to find in the folder where OpenVPN is installed an example of the `${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}` file. I would appreciate any help, guidance, or link to the documentation or example of `${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}`.

Regards,

Rando

---

Update................02.28.2021

I have tried to use network manager to establish a VPN connection.  When creating a new OpenVPN connection with the network manager I need to enter the following information:

- Name: ComapnyVPN
- Gateway: openvpn.company.io
- Type: password
- Username: user@email.com
- Password: mypassword
- Ca certificate: This information I don't have. I asked the It guy for a certificate and he replied by saying I don't need it, and that I should install the OpenVPN from this [link](https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/)

I have only this information the **URL, email, and password**. With this information, I am trying to establish a connection with VPN. I am not finding any example on how to create `${CONFIGURATION_PROFILE_NAME}` file.

Comment: Did you get a configuration profile file from your office IT people? It may have the file extension .ovpn. See [How can I use a .ovpn file with Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187511/how-can-i-use-a-ovpn-file-with-network-manager)

Comment: I use openvpn all the time, but I don't have a dedicated client program. You can just use network manager. Just right click it, select edit connections, then add connection and go through the steps of putting in your connection info.

Comment: Hi, thank your time for taking your time [@user68186, @Organic Marble] to answer this question.  I have updated the question with the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setup OpenVPN with `ovpn` file using GUI

### Get the `ovpn` file

Login to **openvpn.company.io** in the web browser with credentials (username: **user@email.com,** pass: **mypassword**). If you are not able to access the **openvpn.company.io** on browser you should talk with IT person to grant you access.

After you are successfully logged in download the **client.ovpn** file in your Downloads folder.

### Setup VPN from Settings App

Open the settings app and go to the Network tab on the left:

[image]

Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to **VPN** as shown above.

### Import from file...

Select **Import from file...** from the **Add VPN** window.

[image]

**Note**: Do not click on the **OpenVPN** option above. This will ask you to fill in all sorts of things you don't need when you have the `ovpn` file.

Select the `client.ovpn` file from your Downloads folder and open it. This will give you the next window.

### Username and Password

[image]

- The name of the VPN should be filled, but you can change it to
  something you want.
- The Gateway should also be filled. Do not change it.
- Enter your user name: **user@email.com**
- Enter your Password: **mypassword**
- The CA certificate should be filled. Do not change it.

Click on the ADD button. Your username and password will be saved.

### Turn on VPN

You can turn VPN on and off from the setting window. Or from the drop down list at the top right corner of the desktop under Wired and WiFi connections.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by login to **openvpn.company.io** in the web browser with credentials (username: **user@email.com**, pass: **mypassword**). If you are not able to access the **openvpn.company.io** on browser you should talk with IT person to grant you access.

After you are successfully logged in download the **client.ovpn** file. Then from here everything is pretty easy. You should just follow the instruction in this [link](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/).