# Ubuntu 22.04 OpenVPN config

Tags: networking, 22.04, vpn, openvpn

I have .ovpn file, exported from OpenVPN server:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194 udp
lport 0
verify-x509-name "C=xxx, ST=xxx, L=xxx, O=xxx, emailAddress=xxx@xxx.xxx, CN=xxx" subject
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo adaptive
pkcs12 xxx.p12
tls-auth xxx-tls.key 1
```

Sure I have auth.txt, xxx.p12 and xxx-tls.key files, exported from the same OpenVPN server

**Can anyone please explain me, what have I do to config client with this files on Ubuntu 22.04?**

I've installed openvpn (`apt-get install openvpn`)

Put all the files to `/etc/openvpn/client`

Tried to `openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client/xxx.ovpn`

Have an error `Cannot pre-load keyfile (xxx-tls.key)`

I'm not sure these steps are right...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a .ovpn file with Network Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187511/how-can-i-use-a-ovpn-file-with-network-manager)

Comment: No, I have only ssh access, so I need to configure it with console

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for me:

1. Export one .ovpn file from server instead of several:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194 udp
lport 0
verify-x509-name "C=xxx, ST=xxx, L=xxx, O=xxx, emailAddress=xxx@xxx.xxx, CN=xxx" subject
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo adaptive
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
***DATA***
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
***DATA***
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
***DATA***
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
***DATA***
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
key-direction 1
```

2. Rename .ovpn file to `client.conf`
3. Copy `client.conf` and `auth.txt` to `/etc/openvpn`
4. Run `systemctl start openvpn@client`